# Lists fills 2 times "remember me" ticked at Login Page

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a xamarin forms app. I'm a new developer.
I have a login page and there are some comboboxedits (picker) in it.
My combobox edits are Database, company, substation. When user pick database company fills, then pick company and substation fills and then user pick a substation.
This works well like this but I want to add "remember me" function to my app.

I got information and save them to login. I used "selectedItem" property to pick item in comboboxedits. When loginpage open these lists fills 2 times.

Here is my code.

```
async void pageStartFun()
    {
        fillDatabasePicker();
        await beniHatirla();



    }

 async Task beniHatirla()
    {

        hatirla = "hatirla";

        if (hatirla == "hatirla")
        {
            string db = Preferences.Get("myDB", "");
            DatabaseModel d = new DatabaseModel { DBKOD = db };
            FirmaModel f = new FirmaModel { FIRNO = fno };
            SubeModel s = new SubeModel { SUBEADI = subeAd };

            SelectedDatabaseModel = d;

            FirmaModel = f;
            SubeModel = s;
            Username = username;
            Password = pass;
            OnPropertyChanged();    
       }

    }
```

Xaml:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit  
                            
                            x:Name="subePicker"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding SubeList}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SubeModel}"
                            
                            DisplayMember="SUBEADI"
                            BackgroundColor="White"
                            LabelText="Şube"
                            Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" 
                            LabelColor="Black"  
                            TextFontSize="18"
                            LabelFontSize="18"
                            DropDownItemFontSize="18"
                            BottomTextFontSize="18"
                            AffixFontSize="18"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            TextFontFamily="Roboto"
                            AffixFontFamily="Roboto"
                            BottomTextFontFamily="Roboto"
                            DropDownItemFontFamily="Roboto"
                            DropDownItemTextColor="Black"
                            DropDownSelectedItemTextColor="Black"                                 
                            TextHorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            Margin="0,0,0,10"
                            TextColor="Black"  />
```

Function to fill subelist. This list fills when firma selected. But it fills 2 times when page start.
async void fillSubeList()
{

```
        try
        {
            SubeList.Clear();

            if (FirmaModel != null)
            {
                var subelst = await serviceManager.getSubeList();

                foreach (var item in subelst)
                {
                    SubeList.Add(item);
                    
                }
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
        
    }
```

[image]

Comment: its hard to tell what's going on from the snippets you posted, but the easiest way to track this down is to use the debugger to determine where the method is getting called

Comment: I changed function names and somethings broke. Then I fixed with new named function. After that I changed my logic. Lists fills when user select item. Not lists fills after unfocused method. I fixed my problem somehow. Thanks for your advice.  @Jason